# VB.NET - Load files based on combo box selected index

Tags: .net

Ok, so I'm doing a fingerprint recognition system whereby I have to load the fingerprint template and verify if the template and the input on the device is match.

So what I have done is to retrieve all the template that saved in my desktop (.fpt) and added to combo box.

Now I'm trying to get if the SelectedIndex, 
(for instance: Melanie.fpt is selected from the combo box, then system should load the file, then I will verify if the input matches the template)

Below is the code for my combo box (successfully loaded into my combo box)

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.fpt")
        cmbTemplateFiles.Items.Add(foundFile)
    Next
```

**Question**

1. how do I let the system know if this selected index is referring to the particular file?
2. after selecting, click on the button, systems will retrieve the file base on index selected, then i will do the comparison and verification
3. but i have not still figured out, can anyone spark me with idea nor logic?

Comment: `Dim dir = "C : \Users\Kobe88\Desktop\Templates"
        Dim openfile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Dir, cmbTemplateFiles.SelectedItem.Value.ToString)
        'start the process using the openfile string
        'Process.Start(openfile)
        Process.Start(cmbTemplateFiles.SelectedItem.Value)`


I have tried code above to open the file base on selected index value, but it does not open up the file but giving me error for the second line of code as per below

** System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found.'**

Comment: Really not sure what you are asking.  The selected file would be `cmbTemplateFiles.SelectedItem.ToString`.

Comment: @LarsTech, sorry for the bad explanation, btw I've found the solution to my problem and your comment did contribute to part of it. much thanks!!